# Can I float:right Image1 one on top of Image2 if image1 and image2 are in the same container?

Tags: css-float, floating

Here is my problem http://jsfiddle.net/hkebxend/ I want to move that woman to the top right corner of section#historia and on top with that flowers image with float:right (NOT WITH position:absolute BUT with float:right).

HTML:

```
<section id="historia">
      <div class="pasek-one">
              <span class="data-one">1940-1950</span>
      </div>
      <div class="zdjecie-one"></div>
      <p class="tekst-one">
      Rodzina Tatomirów przeprowadza się z Lwowa do Krakowa pod koniec I Wojny Światowej. Na początku lat 20. Tomasz Tatomir – 
      pierwszy przedstawiciel fryzjerskiego rodu Tatomirów – rozpoczyna praktykę na Rynku Głównym w Krakowie. To tam zyskuje przydomek 
      „Roman”. W 1927 roku Tomasz „Roman” Tatomir na krakowskim Placu Inwalidów otwiera swój pierwszy salon (na zdjęciu). Wkrótce 
      wybucha jednak II Wojna Światowa. „Roman” jest zmuszony do opuszczenia salonu. Zaraz po wojnie otwiera zakład fryzjerski na 
      nowo – tym razem w swoim domu rodzinnym na Bronowicach.
      </p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed css a bit of div.pasek-one and added properties `float:left; width:70%` and i think you want exactly the same result

sorry. understood it a bit wrong. here is the fiddle with corrected css http://jsfiddle.net/gopal280377/tpmchbd5/

Answer (score 0):

Just changed the structure of the divs - moved the

```
<div class="zdjecie-one"></div>
```

inside the pasek-one. See the code below with no CSS changes

```
<section id="historia">
      <div class="pasek-one">
              <span class="data-one">1940-1950</span>
        <div class="zdjecie-one"></div>
      </div>

      <p class="tekst-one">
      Rodzina Tatomirów przeprowadza się z Lwowa do Krakowa pod koniec I Wojny Światowej. Na początku lat 20. Tomasz Tatomir – 
      pierwszy przedstawiciel fryzjerskiego rodu Tatomirów – rozpoczyna praktykę na Rynku Głównym w Krakowie. To tam zyskuje przydomek 
      „Roman”. W 1927 roku Tomasz „Roman” Tatomir na krakowskim Placu Inwalidów otwiera swój pierwszy salon (na zdjęciu). Wkrótce 
      wybucha jednak II Wojna Światowa. „Roman” jest zmuszony do opuszczenia salonu. Zaraz po wojnie otwiera zakład fryzjerski na 
      nowo – tym razem w swoim domu rodzinnym na Bronowicach.
      </p>
</section>
```